# Deserialize JSON string (array of JSON objects) back into array of R classes

Tags: r, list

I got the following in the property "tags" of p2 (class):

```
p2 <- list(tags=read.table(text="
   id     name
1 123 tag_test
2 456  unknown", header=T))
```

I want to deserialize `p2$tags[1,]` and `p2$tags[2,]` back into an object `Tag` (with the property "id", "name").

I tried with jsonlite::toJSON but got the following:

```
> jsonlite::toJSON(p2$tags[2,])
[{"id":456,"name":"unknown"}]
```

but I don't need array of JSON objects. I just need `{"id":456,"name":"unknown"}`

So here are my questions:

How can I loop through `p2$tags`?

How to obtain `{"id":456,"name":"unknown"}` instead of array of JSON objects?

UPDATE: here is the JSON string returned by the server

```
{
  "id": 123321,
  "category": {
    "id": 987,
    "name": "cat_test"
  },
  "name": "test",
  "photoUrls": [
    "photo_test",
    "second test"
  ],
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": 123,
      "name": "tag_test"
    },
    {
      "id": 456,
      "name": "unknown"
    }
  ],
  "status": "available"
}
```

and I access `tags` data via `jsonlite::fromJSON(server.response)$tags`

I'm able to deserialize `category` back into a Category class in R but I got no luck doing that with `tags` (List of JSON object). Here is code snippet to do the deserialization:

```
fromJSONString = function(PetJson) {
  PetObject <- jsonlite::fromJSON(PetJson)
  self$`id` <- PetObject$`id`
  self$`category` <- Category$new()$fromJSON(jsonlite::toJSON(PetObject$category, auto_unbox = TRUE))
  self$`name` <- PetObject$`name`
  self$`photoUrls` <- lapply(PetObject$`photoUrls`, function (x) x)
  self$`tags` <- lapply(PetObject$`tags`, function(x) Tag$new()$fromJSON(jsonlite::toJSON(x, auto_unbox = TRUE)))
  self$`status` <- PetObject$`status`
}
```

but I got errors when with the following line:

```
   self$`tags` <- lapply(PetObject$`tags`, function(x) Tag$new()$fromJSON(jsonlite::toJSON(x, auto_unbox = TRUE)))
```

so I tried with the following instead but got the question asked above:

```
   self$`tags` <- sapply(PetObject$`tags`, function(x) x)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to wind up with here. `{"id":456,"name":"unknown"}` isn't a "thing" in R. Is that supposed to be a named list? You seem to be starting with JOSN but then you also seem to be using a `toJSON` so I can't tell if you want to wind up with your data in R or in JSON format. I really don't understand what the desired output is here.

Comment: Would simply removing the square brackets `[` and `]` from the output of `jsonlite::toJSON` get you what you want?

Comment: I obtained the result (JSON string) from the server and I want to parse the fields in the JSON string into R classes or just primitive types (e.g. character), I can do it for all fields except "tags". The desired result is a list of Tag (class). (basically to deserialize JSON string into native R classes)

Comment: There is no such thing as a "Tag" class in R (at least not in base R, are you using some sort of package?). Usually data is just represented as a named list. Where is `Tag$new()` coming from?

Comment: When you "got errors", what errors were they? I understand that the `self$tags` result wasn't what you wanted (or didn't work at all), but what is the goal there----what is it supposed to be? Can you create an example R object manually so we can understand your goal?

Comment: I'd much rather you created a small, illustrative example contained in the question... just one with a clear goal.

Comment: Here is the source code: https://github.com/wing328/petstore-r-client/tree/master/R. Please have a look at Pet.r (line: 145) and Tag.r

Comment: Using `drop = TRUE` fixes the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Just for future reference, when Jason asked *"Would simply removing the square brackets [ and ] from the output of jsonlite::toJSON get you what you want?"*, if you had answered with a simple *"yes"*, instead of *"I want to parse the fields in the JSON string into R classes or just primitive types (e.g. character), I can do it for all fields except "tags". The desired result is a list of Tag (class). (basically to deserialize JSON string into native R classes)"*, I think we could have gotten here a lot faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p2$tags[2,]` is a data frame, which is why it gets boxed in `[` to be an array. If we use the `drop = TRUE` command in the subset it will be a `list` which is not boxed.

```
toJSON(p2$tags[2, ], auto_unbox = TRUE)
# [{"id":456,"name":"unknown"}] 
toJSON(p2$tags[2, , drop = TRUE], auto_unbox = TRUE)
# {"id":456,"name":"unknown"}
```

Similarly, if we call `x` the `fromJSON()` reading of the object you provide,

```
toJSON(x$tags[2, , drop = TRUE], auto_unbox = TRUE)
# {"id":456,"name":"unknown"}
```

This answers your query *"How to obtain `{"id":456,"name":"unknown"}` instead of array of JSON objects?"* I have no idea what you mean when you say you want to "deserialize JSON string into native R classes".

Comment: Thanks @Gregor I agree the subject is not very clear. I've updated the question with more information on why I want to convert JSON string obtained from server back into native R class.

Comment: Or another option may be `unclass`

Comment: Sure, `unclass`, `as.list`, probably others will work too.